# How to hide footer if someone checks your site from a link on a specific website

Tags: php, javascript

I recently started to develop an interest in freelancing. I just created an account on vWorker, but it seems they do not alow linking to sites that have your personal information.

That means that I can not link to my website portfolio, unless I find a way to hide the footer when someone clicks on the link from them.

Is there a way that I can hide my footer when someone clicks on the link on this page?

- [my vworker portfiolio](http://www.vworker.com/RentACoder/DotNet/SoftwareCoders/ShowBioInfo.aspx?lngAuthorId=8262781&Tab=2)

The footer should be hidden only for this scenarion.

Comment: I doubt this'll pass muster with vWorker.

Comment: @ceejayoz why? If its a matter of you not allowing this information to be displayed then there is no reason they wouldn't allow it, unless there is some other rule in place.

Comment: they seem to not alow you to link to your contact information or share your contact information on your profile so I figure if I hide it when you link from there website no harm done

Comment: If they're on your website, they could do a WHOIS. WHOIS on foxteam.net gives your e-mail, name, and address. This is likely considered a violation of vWorker's terms.

Comment: @ceejayoz I doubt it very much.  If their terms state that you cannot display your information.  Secondly if it really was a violation just get a private registration so it doesn't appear on WHOIS, not difficult.

Comment: @JonTaylor These contract worker sites tend to be pretty unforgiving. I'm not the one at risk, so I really don't care all that much. It's user985482's profile that'll disappear, not mine.

Comment: @ceejayoz I never said it was, I never said you should be bothered, I was simply stating that a WHOIS lookup is not the end of the world as you can easily request a private registry on it.  Also as I said **if** the rules as he stated are that you just cannot display your information then removing based on a referrer address would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: and I'm stressing that assuming anything here is probably a bad idea. Frankly, the best thing the OP could do would be to contact vWorker support and ask if his proposed solution is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in jquery i would start hiding the footer, making it hidden by default, then showing it in other cases

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (document.referrer.indexOf("http://www.xyz.com")==-1) 
        $("#footer").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Javascripts `document.referrer` possibly, to check where they came from?  Then if it is being referred from a particular domain fire some Javascript which will remove the footer.

I would definitely suggest removing the contact information rather than hiding it too.